# Update Panel and Timer Not working in list View

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a list view and I am trying to refresh it using an update panel and a timer for trigger. I have tried everything I know but I can get it to update the Listview, but I used a label to test with Time Now which works. So the update panel and trigger are working, but the listview is not refreshing.

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="100" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="displayFollowers" DataKeyNames="ProfileId"></asp:ListView>

     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="DataBinding" />
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Show your code behind.

Comment: @king.code i dont have have any code behinjd. The listview is connected to a datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be calling `ListView2.DataBind()` in the `Timer_Tick` event for that to work.  It does not automatically refresh once initially bound.